# Probability of Detection confidence interval

Tags: probability

I am dealing a Probability of Density curve. I have the curve fitted but need to apply a $95\%$ confidence interval for that curve. The parameters of the curve are as follows: $$-5.0793 x^2+ 4.853x- .1618$$

…where $x$ is a percentage between $0$ and 100.

I tried using the formula for the lower one sided confidence bound. Standard normal distribution $(z-h)$ where $$z=\frac{\ln(a)-\mu}{\text{S.D.}}$$ where

- $a$ is a percentage
- $h=\sqrt{\dfrac y{nk_0} \left[1+\dfrac{(k_0z+k_1)^2}{k_0k_2-k_1^2}\right]}$
  where $k_0,_1,_2$ are the three parameters and $y$ is gamma the vale of the confidence bound.

When I use this formula I get unrealistic bounds for the problem. $\mu$ and $\rm S.D.$ come from the average and standard deviation of the sample. When I use this formula I get unrealistic bounds. Is there another formula I should use or another way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this  reference may be, is very useful,

[Berens A (1988) NDE reliability data analysis, vol 17, Metals Handbook,
9th edition, pp 689–701]